# Android Studio Not working. Sdk not downloading

Tags: android

I have now been stuck on this problem for about 3 weeks now. My android studio wont work. I dont even know the problem nothing's working. [image: Component Installer Error]

[image: 'TestApp' project refresh failed]

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

1. First, Download the sdk from [here](https://dl.google.com/android/repository/sdk-tools-windows-3859397.zip) , then extract zip file and install the required packages.
2. Open the Android Studio **>** File **>** Close Project
3. Hope you reach this screen:[image]
4. Select **>** configure **>** project defaults **>** project structure
5. Following screen would appear:[image]
6. Enter your sdk location and click apply

I cannot gurantee it will work but you can try. It took me quite a while to install android studio too.